# Optimal implementation of cryptographic function of exponentiation by modulus in Rust

Tags: rust, cryptography

I try to use the [num-bigint crate](https://github.com/rust-num/num-bigint) to implement such a formula `( ( a ^ b ) % c )`, where `a`, `b` and `c` are integers of an arbitrary length and `^` the operation of exponentiation, and `%` the operation of finding the reminder. But I faced two problems.

1. seems num-bigint does not have single function implementing `( ( a ^ b ) % c )` optimally
2. num-bigint is not zero-copy. To make an instance of `BigUint` you need to make a copy of the original data `Vec <u8>`, and then copy the result again from `BigUint` to `Vec <u8>`.

Is it possible to solve these problems within this module? If not, please advise another module?

Comment: [`modpow`](https://docs.rs/num-bigint/0.4.2/num_bigint/struct.BigInt.html#method.modpow) is a very common operation for big-integer libraries to provide, and `num-bigint` is no exception. However, I don't think it provides an in-place version of it exists.

Comment: Aha! It solves 1st problem. Thanks!

Comment: [Zero-copy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-copy) explained

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use function [modpow](https://docs.rs/num-bigint/0.4.2/num_bigint/struct.BigUint.html#method.modpow) as suggested. It seems num does not support zero-copy. Function `new` copy data from a vector. Same is relevant to `from_slice`, `from_bytes_le`, `from_bytes_be`. Moreover current implementation of `from_bytes_le` is sub-optimal.